# Referring to element without document

Tags: javascript, html

Why is it possible to refer to an element in HTML via JS without the need to go through document? And is this recommended?

For example

index.html

```
<canvas id="elem" onclick="foo();">
```

script.js

```
function foo() {
    elem.width = 100;
    elem.height = 100;
}
```

Comment: Use `onclick="foo(this)"` it will actually give you the element. Or via event properties... Try debugger to see what is hidden in the event. I think that `event.target` should give you the element too

Comment: It's a *feature* some browser vendors implement. You should **not** rely on it as the auto-variables may be redefined by scripts

Comment: @PranavCBalan if you manage the code so that there are no global variables, then I think this is fine. Supports all modern browsers.

Comment: @Akxe but even without `this` that code above will actually works

Comment: @Mr_Green—creating global variables from element IDs has always been considered a bad feature that was introduced by ancient IE and copied by other browsers for compatibility (when IE had 95% marketshare). It should not be used.